# Change size of SqueezeBox using javascript

Tags: javascript, squeezebox

Hi I have this JS CODE

```
function openPopup(url)
{

    var newElem = new Element( 'div' );
    newElem.setAttribute('rel','handler');
    newElem.setAttribute('class','modal');
    SqueezeBox.setContent( 'adopt', newElem );
    SqueezeBox.setContent( 'iframe', url);

}
```

This open a popup with the given URL.I'd like to change the size of the SqueezeBox how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try
    SqueezeBox.resize({x: 350, y: 400});

Of course you have to resize your content also, as in

```
SqueezeBox.initialize({
    size: {x: 350, y: 400}
});

var newElem = new Element( 'div' );
newElem.appendText("Some Text");
newElem.setStyle('border', 'solid 2px black');
newElem.setStyle('width', '300px');
SqueezeBox.setContent('adopt', newElem);

SqueezeBox.resize({x: 750, y: 400})
newElem.setStyle('width', '700px');
```

Comment: Soory, But I got A litel problem here, the content of the SqueezeBox does not fill with the entier size of the SqueezeBox I'mean even If i changed the size of the SqueezeBox the content it's self is show I just shonw in a limeted space

Comment: Hi, Sorry I'f I'm late here is the code

function openPopup(url)
{

SqueezeBox.initialize({
    size: {x: 350, y: 400}
});

var newElem = new Element( 'div' );
SqueezeBox.setContent('adopt', newElem);
SqueezeBox.setContent( 'iframe', url);
SqueezeBox.setContent( 'iframe', url);
SqueezeBox.resize({x: 750, y: 400})

newElem.setStyle('width', '700px');



}

I don't relay know why I have ti put this code twice 
SqueezeBox.setContent( 'iframe', url);
I'f I dont put it I got a blanc SqueezeBox, 
And If i put it twice The content of the squeezeBox is not what I want it